# Check a given word in each cell and extract it to put in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiple column and in one of a column There is a paragraph written along with a keyword. I need to extract that keyword and put it in an array.

EX: [image: Example]

Now I have to go through every row of column 3 and find Keyword "TEST" and extract after : word. Like ENGLISH, MATH, PSYCHLOGY etc into an array.
Further I'll create a text file and make a sentance using these extracted words. I am not able to find exact logic to extract these words.

Comment: instead of an image, you should consider posting the data. eg copy the results of `df.head(3).to_dict()` and paste it in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract` as follows:

```
temp = df['column3'].str.extract('TEST:(.*)')
```

For the second part if I understand you well:

```
temp.to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: This worked well somewhat. Able to extract the words into a new column temp. But header is missing and without header. I am unable to append all the extracted words into an array.

Comment: The result is a Series. What do you mean by appending to array? you can use temp.values to have a numpy array.

Comment: Why do you want an array?

Comment: So I need these words in an array like arr=['ENGLISH', 'MATH', 'PSYCHLOGY']. I will use this array for further data formation.

Comment: So just use temp.values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.Series.str.extract`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    'col3': ['a\n\nTEST: MATH', 'b\nTEST: ENG', 'c\n\nTEST: PSY']
})

df['col3'].str.extract('TEST:(.*)$')
```

Comment: Thanks @kang It looks good. But the resultant column3 is having no header. And I want to put those extracted word in an array.